# Word Cloud from Highcharts - Create a placement strategy so words are ordered from highest weight to lowest

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a placement strategy for Word Cloud from Highcharts so that the words themselves are placed based on their weight, from highest to lowest. I'm not entirely sure how to create this placement strategy based on their docs.  Any help would be great!

I have this jfiddle with no rotation: https://jsfiddle.net/3gp2L1zw/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    accessibility: {
        screenReaderSection: {
            beforeChartFormat: '<h5>{chartTitle}</h5>' +
                '<div>{chartSubtitle}</div>' +
                '<div>{chartLongdesc}</div>' +
                '<div>{viewTableButton}</div>'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: data,
        name: 'Occurrences',
        rotation: {
        from: 0,
        to: 0
        }
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation placed below, I created a simplified demo where I added another method to the `placementStrategy`.
DOCS: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/word-cloud-series#custom-spiralling-algorithm

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/14q9hxvj/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!